# How to calculate cost by querying for a particular field in a row

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have the following data

```
Cust No.  |  Action       | Val
----------| --------------| ----
10        | Checked out   | 1.0
10        | PAID          | 40.0
10        | Checked In    | 1.0
15        | Flew Away     | 2.0
15        | PAID          | 100.00
15        | Came back     | 1.0
20        | PAID          | 150.00
30        | Checked In    | 1.0
30        | PAID          | 50.00
30        | PAID          | 10.00
```

How can I get the `SUM` of only the `PAID` values for each customer with a `Checked In` entry

i.e.

```
Cust No.  |  Total Paid       
----------| --------------
30        | 60.00
10        | 40.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 select customer.customer_number, sum(value) as total_paid  from customers
    left join
    (
      select customer_number from users where action = 'Checked In' group by customer_number
    )checkins on checkins.customer_number = customers.customer_number 
    where checkins.customer_number is not null and customers.action = 'PAID'
    group by customers.customer_number
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select customer_number, sum(value) as total_paid 
from table_name where action = 'PAID' group by customer_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` condition along with `SUM` like

```
sum(case when Action = 'paid' then val end)
```

What if you tweak your query a bit using a outer query like

```
select customer_number, PaymentDone
from (
select customer_number, 
sum(case when Action = 'paid' then val end) as PaymentDone,
group_concat(Action ORDER BY Action asc) as Action_List 
from tbl1
group by customer_number) xxx
where Action_List like 'Checked In%';
```

Comment: I think limiting with a where clause will be faster

Comment: @NickEllis, Nope and moreover don't think rather try it out. Try the both query and get the execution plan and compare yourself

Comment: @Rahul This isn't taking into account ONLY the entries with `Checked In` it is calculating all with `paid`

Comment: @Anthony, see edit in answer if that helps. You should clarify all this while posting the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Spark to test on, however one way should be to use `HAVING` to figure out if there's a 'Checked In' row in the group;

```
SELECT `Cust No`, SUM(CASE WHEN Action='PAID' THEN val END) paid 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY `Cust No` 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Action='Checked In' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0

+---------+------+
| Cust No | paid |
+---------+------+
|      10 |   40 |
|      30 |   60 |
+---------+------+
```

Another is to do the selection using `WHERE` to find the groups first and only sum them;

```
SELECT `Cust No`, SUM(val) paid 
FROM mytable 
WHERE action='PAID' AND `Cust No` IN (
  SELECT `Cust No` FROM mytable WHERE action='Checked In'
) 
GROUP BY `Cust No`
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned before. I am trying to do this in spark-sql. The `having` clause you provided isn't working. It errors with `filter expression 'havingCondition' of type int is not a boolean.` I'm sure this is because of spark-sql. I've edited the tags for the question accordingly